# Calculating Page Table Size

Tags: memory-management, paging

I'm reading through an example of page tables and just found this:

***Consider a system with a 32-bit logical address space. If the page size in such a system is 4 KB (2^12), then a page table may consist of up to 1 million entries (2^32/2^12). Assuming that each entry consists of 4 bytes, each process may need up to 4 MB of physical address space for the page table alone.***

I don't really understand what this 4MB result represents. Does it represent the space the actual page table takes up?

Comment: Just for information, this line is from Operating System Concepts, Avi Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin, Greg Gagne - Section 8.5.1 in the 8th edition.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Since we have a virtual address space of **2^32** and each page size is **2^12**, we can store **(2^32/2^12) = 2^20 pages**. Since each entry into this page table has an address of size 4 bytes, then we have **2^20*4 = 4MB**. So the **page table takes up 4MB in memory**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explanation, i could not understand: if page size is 2^12 bytes why we are not converting it to bits like (2^12 bytes = 2 ^ 15 bits) and then calculate division 2^32 (bits) / 2^15 (bits) = 2^17 (max possible number of pages)? Why use bytes?

Comment: @MukhtarBimurat Each address is pointing at one whole byte in memory. Individual bits are not addressable. So you are able to address 2^32 bytes. The page table is a mapping from virtual address space to physical address space. But it does not map individual bytes, but maps in chunks called pages. Pages in this example are 2^12 bytes large. Therefore your page table needs 2^32/2^12=2^20 entries to map all possible pages.

Comment: Also note that MB technically should be MiB, which is 2^20 bytes as opposed to 10^6 bytes.

Answer (score 25):

My explanation uses elementary building blocks that helped me to understand. Note I am leveraging [@Deepak Goyal's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803842/3761924) since he provided clarity:

We were given a logical 32-bit address space (i.e. We have a 32 bit computer)

> Consider a system with a 32-bit logical address space

- This means that every memory address can be 32 bits long.
- "A 32-bit entry can point to one of 2^32 physical page frames"[2], stated differently,
- ["A 32-bit register can store 2^32 different values"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit)

We were also told that

> each page size is 4 KB

- 1 KB (kilobyte) = 1 x 1024 bytes = 2^10 bytes
- 4 x 1024 bytes = 2^2 x 2^10 bytes => 4 KB (i.e. 2^12 bytes)
- The size of each page is thus 4 **KB** (Kilo**bytes** NOT kilo**bits**).

As Depaak said, we calculate the number of pages in the page table with this formula:

```
Num_Pages_in_PgTable = Total_Possible_Logical_Address_Entries / page size 
Num_Pages_in_PgTable =         2^32                           /    2^12
Num_Pages_in_PgTable = 2^20 (i.e. 1 million)
```

The authors go on to give the case where each entry in the page table takes 4 bytes. That means that the total size of the page table in **physical memory** will be 4MB:

```
Memory_Required_Per_Page = Size_of_Page_Entry_in_bytes x Num_Pages_in_PgTable
Memory_Required_Per_Page =           4                 x     2^20
Memory_Required_Per_Page =     4 MB (Megabytes)
```

So yes, each process would require at least 4MB of memory to run, in increments of 4MB.

### Example

Now if a professor wanted to make the question a bit more challenging than the explanation from the book, they might ask about a 64-bit computer. Let's say they want memory in **bits**. To solve the question, we'd follow the same process, only being sure to convert MB to Mbits.

Let's step through this example.

### Givens:

> - Logical address space: 64-bit
> - Page Size: 4KB
> - Entry_Size_Per_Page: 4 bytes

Recall: A 64-bit entry can point to one of 2^64 physical page frames
    - Since Page size is 4 KB, then we still have **2^12** byte page sizes

> - 1 KB (kilobyte) = 1 x 1024 bytes = 2^10 bytes
> - Size of each page = 4 x 1024 bytes = 2^2 x 2^10 bytes = 2^12 bytes

### How Many pages In Page Table?

```
`Num_Pages_in_PgTable = Total_Possible_Logical_Address_Entries / page size 
Num_Pages_in_PgTable =         2^64                            /    2^12
Num_Pages_in_PgTable =         2^52 
Num_Pages_in_PgTable =      2^2 x 2^50 
Num_Pages_in_PgTable =       4  x 2^50 `
```

### How Much Memory in BITS Per Page?

```
Memory_Required_Per_Page = Size_of_Page_Entry_in_bytes x Num_Pages_in_PgTable 
Memory_Required_Per_Page =   4 bytes x 8 bits/byte    x     2^52
Memory_Required_Per_Page =     32 bits                x   2^2 x 2^50
Memory_Required_Per_Page =     32 bits                x    4  x 2^50
Memory_Required_Per_Page =     128 Petabits
```

[2]: Operating System Concepts (9th Ed) - Gagne, Silberschatz, and Galvin

Answer (score 5):

**Suppose logical address space is ***32 bit*** so total possible logical entries will be ***2^32*** and other hand suppose each page size is ***4 kilobyte*** then size of one page is ***2^2*2^10=2^12...***
now we know that no. of pages in page table is
pages=total possible logical address entries/page size
so ***pages=2^32/2^12 =2^20***
Now suppose that each entry in page table takes 4 bytes then total size of page table in ***physical memory will be=2^2*2^20=2^22=4mb*****

Answer (score 5):

In 32 bit virtual address system we can have 2^32 unique address, since the page size given is 4KB = 2^12, we will need (2^32/2^12 = 2^20) entries in the page table, if each entry is 4Bytes then total size of the page table = 4 * 2^20 Bytes = 4MB

Answer (score 4):

Since the Logical Address space is 32-bit long that means program size is 2^32 bytes i.e. 4GB.
Now we have the page size of 4KB i.e.2^12 bytes.Thus the number of pages in program are 2^20.(no. of pages in program = program size/page size).Now the size of page table entry is 4 byte hence the size of page table is 2^20*4 = 4MB(size of page table = no. of pages in program * page table entry size). Hence 4MB space is required in Memory to store the page table.

Comment: "Since the Logical Address space is 32-bit long that means program size is 2^32 bytes???" Didn't you just confused bits with bytes?

Comment: If I am not wrong,'Logical Address space is 32-bit long' means we can store up to 2^32 numbers i.e 2^32 memory addresses and each memory address/location can store 1 byte data so in total you can store 2^32 bytes of data

Answer (score 1):

yes it represents the space the actual page table takes for one process.

if each page is 4KB -> 12 bits for offset (how?)

1 kb is 2^10 bytes => 4 kb is 4*2^10 bytes which is 2^12 => hence 12 bits for offset and the remaining 20 bits for VPN => 2^20 translations which means 2^20 pages are there which means 2^20 entries in the page table.

Hence, size of page table = number of entries in the page table * size of one entry

=> size of page table = 2^20 * 4 KB = 2^22 kB and 1 MB is 2^20 KB => 4 MB