# Calculating the table entry size

Tags: memory, frames, virtual-memory, page-tables

I got a question like this and need to calculate the table entry size.

Microsoft Windows 98 used a 32-bit memory address space while the default page size was 4KB. If it is having a physical memory of 256MB

i)  What is the size of an entry in the page table?

Does this equal to page offset?

Comment: What is the other homework question?

Comment: Is the  TLB entry is the same size as a page or frame? Really appreciate if someone can help...  I tries searching...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017488/what-is-page-table-entry-size might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Page Table Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323890/calculating-page-table-size)

Answer (score 1):

In 32-bit Intel, the page table entry is 32-Bits.

Answer (score 0):

Size of an entry in the page table is 32-12 = 20.

Comment: please reconsider your answer.