# How many entries are there in an inverted page table?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Consider a computer system with 48-bit logical address space and 2Kbytes page size. The system has  1 Gbytes of physical memory. How many entries are there in an inverted page table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Page Table Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323890/calculating-page-table-size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Number of entries in inverted page table = physical address space  / page size

Physical address space= 1GB =2^30
Page size = 2KB= 2^11

Number of entries =2 ^ (30-11) =2^19 =512K entries.

Answer (score 0):

As it can be inferred from its name, if size of physical memory is 2^m frame then size of inverted page table must be 2^m. In your specific case, size (number of entries) of inverted page table is = 2^30.
The inverted page table is used by all processes,which is consist of(process-id , page number, control bits )
Benefits:
1)Reduce overhead of creating page table for each process
2)nverted Page tables are sorted in order of frame number but the memory look-up takes place with respect to the virtual address, so, it usually takes a longer time to find the appropriate entry but often these page tables are implemented using hash data structures for a faster lookup.
for more >>> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inverted-page-table-in-operating-system/